In a trigger check if one of 24 columns are updated (postgres)
I have a table with 50 columns.
I need to make a trigger to do something, i can do that, but i need to do whene 1 of 24 columns are updated.
The problem is i have to do 24 times
if NEW.column <> OLD.column THEN
ELSEIF NEW.column2 <> OLD.column2 THEN ....
I was wondering is there other (easy) way to do this check?
Thanks.

You could try to create a "AFTER UPDATE" trigger. This trigger fires on every update in the table, not just if one column changes. I do not know wich DBMS you are using, but PostgreSQL has this:
https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-triggers/postgresql-after-update-trigger/
In PostgreSQL, a trigger is a database object that is fired automatically when an event such as INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or TRUNCATE occurs.

Thenks MArtie, on the title i wrote (postgres), but creating a trigger is not the problem, checking if one of 24 columns are changet is the problem.

There is a specific syntax for this in PostgreSQL, see documentation:
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
AFTER UPDATE OF column_name1, column_name2, column_name3, column_name4, ..., column_name24 ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE FUNCTION function_name;

By using OF column_name the trigger will only be called if that specific column changes.

Thanks Sascha, as i wrote in my message, i can create triggers, i know how to do that, the problem is i dont want to have 24 times IF statements in the trigger, or to create 24 triggers for each column. I am looking some way to minimise this.

@RkassaTeamBreda I understand. You can actually us the OF column_name syntax for multiple columns. I have updated my answer to reflect that, that should work to only create one trigger for 24 columns.

Point of clarification, the "UPDATE OF" syntax only concerns if the column is referenced, not if the value has actually changed.  So if you issue an update and set the column to the same value (or use an ORM that does that) then the trigger will fire even if there is no actual change in the value.

hmm, thanks Jonathan, this i didnot know was possible, but unfortenatly it will not work for me becouse i need to  know which column is changed, becouse i have to do differant things for each column.
